# IsEditable property of WPF combobox

Tags: wpf

I have read in many places that WPF combo does not support autocomplete but I used the IsEditable property and found that the autocomplete was working in WPF 4. Is this a new addition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't

[IsEditable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.iseditable.aspx) has been around since .NET Framework 3.0

Autocompletion usually means displaying the options and filtering those options based on the letters you type. The IsEditable only selects, it does not display.

See what google does in comparison:

[image]

Comment: Thank you but when I type characters in teh WPF combo, it automatically completes it. Isn't this autocomplete?

Comment: Yes it is.. but not autocompletion in the google way. It does not show you the options.