# WPF autocomplete Combobox

Tags: wpf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IsEditable property of WPF combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574334/iseditable-property-of-wpf-combobox)

I have heard that autocomplete does not work (out of box) in WPF combobox but when I type characters in teh WPF combo, it matches existing items of combo and automatically completes it. Isn't this autocomplete?

Am I missing a point?

Answer (score 2):

The WPF combobox does match existing values as you type, but...

Generally when people refer to an autocomplete combobox they mean a combobox that makes a backend query of some sort that will populate the dropdown with new values that match the criteria as the user types.